# How to count occurrences of sequences of values in a data frame?

Tags: r, count, sequence, permutation

I have a data frame with a column of values (treatments assigned by randomisation) 1, 2, 3. Something like:

```
i,treatment
1,1
2,3
3,2
4,2
5,1
6,3
7,3
8,2
9,1
...
```

Each block of 3 rows within the data frame contains a permutation of the three available values, e.g. for rows 1-3 above `(1,3,2)`, for rows 4-6 `(2,1,3)`, for rows 7-9 `(3,2,1)`, etc. The number of rows in the data frame is divisible by 3.

I need to count the occurrences of the permutations - how can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the number of permutations for `i` and `treatment` or just `treatment`? And if only `treatment` are you trying to calculate the number of permutations for each set of 3 rows?

Comment: I want the counts of the permutations of the treatments that occur every 3 rows. Each treatment can only be assigned once per block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, `treatment` is that column in your data frame (whose length is a multiple of 3). Just using your example data, there is `treatment <- c(1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1)`. Then

```
M <- matrix(treatment, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
radix <- 10 ^ (2:0)
ID <- M %*% radix
table(ID)

#132 213 321 
#  1   1   1
```

Perhaps a more accessible version is to use `paste0` to generate `ID` for the permutation index: `ID <- apply(M, 1L, paste0, collapse = "")`, but this would be much less efficient than the matrix-vector multiplication I used above for a very long `treatment` vector.

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` based solution using `count`can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

# Group of every 3 rows
df %>% group_by(grp = (row_number()-1)%/%3) %>%
  #use paste with argument 'collapse' to find distinct permutations. 
  summarise(Permutation = paste(treatment, collapse=",")) %>%
  count(Permutation)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Permutation     n
#   <chr>       <int>
# 1 1,3,2           1
# 2 2,1,3           1
# 3 3,2,1           1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text=
"i,treatment
1,1
2,3
3,2
4,2
5,1
6,3
7,3
8,2
9,1",
header = TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: This also does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.